# Does the new f1 double points rule apply for all places?

Tags: rules, formula-1

From [formula1.com](http://www.formula1.com/news/headlines/2013/12/15339.html):

> Double drivers’ and constructors’ points will be awarded at the final
>   race of the Formula One season - Abu Dhabi for 2014 - in order to
>   maximise focus on the championship until the end of the campaign.

Does this rule also apply for the places outside the points (11th-22nd). Does an 11th place in the last race count as two 11th places? That would be important for the small teams without any points at the end of the championship.

Answer (score 1):

This new rule give duplicate points only for the last race of the season, so:

- the winner takes 25*2=50 points
- the second takes 18*2=36 points

so on from 3rd to 9th arrived

- the 10th takes 1*2=2 points
- the 11th do not takes points

The pilots award only one placement (so no double victory on the same track).

Comment: This is all correct, @Ale but it doesn't specifically answer the poster's question, i.e. when determining who finished first amongst the non-point-scorers in the championship, will the team who finished 11th in the final race be credited with the equivalent of two 11th place finishes thereby potentially beating another back-marker team who "only" finished 11th in one other race.

Comment: As written in the last line, I think (so I cannot assume it like a definitive sentence) that also in this case it will be duplicate only the points